# Combining same action functions

Tags: python, superclass

I am trying to combine similar functions in two different files. What's
the best way to tackle this? I hope to use a base class or something to put similar code in there. Sedan is one file and Truck is another. Want to use base class to combine duplicate code only.

```
 class Sedan(object):
      __init__(self, a, b, c)
      def color():
          return
       def power():
          do something

class Truck(object):
     __init__(self, d, b, c)
      def color():
          return
      def stop():
          action
```

If subclasses have different __ init__ how do you combine them I hope to reduce duplicate code from two different files and put the same functions(only same functions) in the super class. Is there way to combine same functions(such as color in this case) in a easy fashion? I am trying to use base class but any other method will work.

Comment: why do you want to put the same code twice? You said you are trying to use base class, all the functions in base class will be inherited by subclass.

Comment: Referring to the example, I want to create a base class to put duplicate functions there so subclass inherits from the base class. So color() would go into a base class. And I would remove color() from truck and sedan as it inherits from base class.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a base class?

```
class ColoredVehicle(object):
    def color(self):
        return "red"

class Sedan(ColoredVehicle):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c): pass

    def power():
        # do something

class Truck(ColoredVehicle):
    def __init__(self, d, b, c): pass

    def stop():
        # action
```